# Why the MaxPool2d layer of resnet50 outputs 2 tensors when it is visualized in the tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard, resnet

I want to know about why the MaxPool2d layer of resnet50 outputs 2 tensors when it is visualized in the tensorboard? The visualization of resnet50 and code are shown in the following picture. Thank you!

code:

```
import torchvision
import torch
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
import torch.nn as nn
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
dummy_input=torch.rand((10, 3, 224, 224))
with SummaryWriter(comment='Net1')as w:
    w.add_graph(model, (dummy_input,))
```

picture:
[image: The visualization of resnet50]

Comment: Not 100% sure but it might be storing the max indices which probably are required for backprop

Answer (score 0):

The block right next to the max pool in ResNet has a residual connection: that means the input for that block is split between the conv layers and a "direct" path to be added to the output of the conv of that block.

This residual link is marked as "identity" in this diagram:

[image]